# How to open four Sublime Text windows and replace to each corner

Tags: applescript, sublimetext3

What I want to do is

1. Open four "Sublime Text" windows, e.g. type `subl .` for 4 times
2. Replace opened windows to each corner, i.e. one is left-top, one is left-bottom, one is right-top, one is right-bottom

I can do this task manually, however, it's awesome if I can automate this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use split-screen feature of Sublime Text. Below key combination will split your Sublime Text into 4 screens.
- For Linux, shift + alt + 5
- For Mac, cmd + option + 5

Comment: Yes, that's also a useful feature, though, It can not split horizontally and zoom. I'm imagining like a `tmux` customization.

Comment: Oh, now I figured out what you meant. Especially, `cmd + option + 5` seems special command to split into 4 corners, it's slightly different behavior from `cmd + option + 2`, etc. Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is a command line tool [xdotool](https://askubuntu.com/tags/xdotool/info) which will do exactly what you want. Please have a look.